# How to get a height a UITextView should be given width and length of text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am adding a UIView that contains a UITextView which is constrained to the top, left, and bottom of the view.

The width of the UIView should be the screen size's width which in turn will be the UITextView's width.

When I go to create this UIView, I can make it's CGSize to the screen size's width, but I am not sure on how to calculate the height.

How can I figure out what height I must set this UIView so that the UITextView can properly show? Is there a way I can figure out the number of lines a UITextView would have given a certain width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to Get a dynamic Rect:

```
 NSString *myDynamicString = @"Hello World!";
 CGSize textRect = [myDynamicString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT)
                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YouFontName" size:15]}
                                            context:nil];
```

**Note**

> `MAX_WIDTH` Width allowed to expand the rect. If you give 200 then the rect will exapand till 200 and then break and Vice Versa for `MAX_HEIGHT`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! CGSize textRect should be a CGRect also.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(textView.width - 2*textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGFloat messageTextViewHeight = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: textView.font}
                                                       context:nil].size.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

-(CGSize)getSizeForText:(NSString *)text maxWidth:(CGFloat)width font:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(float)fontSize
{

```
CGSize constraintSize;
constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
constraintSize.width = width;

NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName,
                                      nil];

CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                               attributes:attributesDictionary
                                  context:nil];

CGSize stringSize = frame.size;

return stringSize;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using auto-layout this will be done out of the box, you don't have to do anything just setup constraints of auto-layout properly.

`NSSString` API is not very handy (as you can see in other answers) it is easy to miss something. I prfer use `-(CGSize)sizeThatFits:` from `UIView`.

```
UIView *textView = self.textView;
CGSize fitSize = { CGRectGetWidth(textView.frame), CGFLOAT_MAX };
CGSize fitSize = [textView sizeThatFits: fitSize];
NSLog(@"Your desired height: %f", fitSize.height);
```

It is more reliable and it should take into account all properties of text inside `UITextView`. I used this for `UILabel` didn't test for `UITextView` but it should work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all the text in the text view an have the surrounding views around it adapt to contain it the easiest way would be to use a UILabel instead. Then you could just use constraints with priorities. Set the UILabel  number of lines to 0 so that it automatically wraps. Then set the contentCompressionResistancePriority to 1000 for vertical axis. Then you don't need to worry about the sizes. Let autolayout do the work for you.

Comment: This is a great method, but I am actually adding a UIView (with the UITextView inside) with a custom CGRect size so I need to know the size of the text view beforehand.